# Ruby on Rails dynamo db IN statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

How to make IN query with dynamo db

i have tried to do this, but it doens't work if i pass array `page_ids`

```
resp = client.scan({
  expression_attribute_names: {
    '#id' => 'id'
  },
  expression_attribute_values: {
    ":id" => page_ids                      
  },
  filter_expression: '#id IN(:id)',
  table_name: table_name,
})
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend plugging in the [dynamoid](https://github.com/Dynamoid/dynamoid) gem to get an ORM on top of your DDB models. When you do, the following is an example of an in query for DynamoDB using the dynamoid gem.

```
MyModel.where("my_value.in": [1, 2, 3]).batch(25).each do |record|
  p record
end
```